# How to add a marker in Vue2-Leaflet with the popup initially open

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, leaflet

When adding a marker dynamically, how to set the pop up as initially open?

```
<v-map>
  <v-marker v-for="item in markers" :key="item.id" :lat-lng="item.latlng">
    <v-popup :content="item.content"></v-popup>
  </v-marker>
</v-map>
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/manelclos/f7dksf2m/

Comment: If you could setup a live example to work from that'd be very helpful honestly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Vue2leaflet reroutes Leaflet events](https://github.com/KoRiGaN/Vue2Leaflet#how-can-i-bind-events-of-vue2leaflet-components-) to Vue via `l-[leaflet_event]` handlers:

> **How can I bind events of Vue2Leaflet components ?**
>
> All event binding can be done to event called `l-[leaflet_event]`, where
>   `[leaflet_event]` is the name of the event from leaflet documentation.

One possible way to have a popup open by default would be to bind the `openPopup` method of the marker to its `add` event.

For example, with an inline handler:

```html
<v-map :zoom="zoom" :center="center">
    <v-marker v-for="item in markers" :key="item.id" :lat-lng="item.latlng"
        @l-add="$event.target.openPopup()"
    >
        <v-popup :content="item.content"></v-popup>
    </v-marker>
</v-map>
```

An updated Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/f7dksf2m/2/ and a demo

```js
Vue.component('v-map', Vue2Leaflet.Map);
Vue.component('v-tilelayer', Vue2Leaflet.TileLayer);
Vue.component('v-marker', Vue2Leaflet.Marker);
Vue.component('v-popup', Vue2Leaflet.Popup);

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
        return {
            zoom: 13,
            center: [47.417220, -1.219482],
            url: 'http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
            marker: L.latLng(47.413220, -1.219482),

            markers: []
        }
    },
    mounted () {
      window.setTimeout( () => {
        this.markers.push({
          id: 1,
          latlng: L.latLng(47.417220, -1.222482),
          content: 'Hi! this is my popup data'
        });
      }, 1000);

      window.setTimeout( () => {
        this.markers.push({
          id: 2,
          latlng: L.latLng(47.417220, -1.24),
          content: 'Another'
        });
      }, 2000);

      this.$refs.map.mapObject.on('add', (e) => {
        console.log(e)

      });
    }
});
```

```css
html, body, #app {
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue2-leaflet@0.0.58/dist/vue2-leaflet.js"></script>

  <div id="app">
    <v-map ref='map' :zoom="zoom" :center="center">
      <v-tilelayer :url="url" :attribution="attribution"></v-tilelayer>
      <v-marker :lat-lng="marker"></v-marker>
        <v-marker v-for="item in markers" :key="item.id" :lat-lng="item.latlng" @l-add="$event.target.openPopup()">
          <v-popup :content="item.content"></v-popup>
        </v-marker>
    </v-map>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

nikoshr solution doesn't work for leaflet 1.4. Try this instead :

```
<l-map>
  <l-marker @add="$nextTick(() => $event.target.openPopup())">
    <l-popup></l-popup>
  </l-marker>
</l-map>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hponcede/839nzgy7/4/